# How to cache results in scala?

Tags: scala, caching

[This page](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~odersky/whatsnew/collections-api/collections_10.html) has a description of Map's `getOrElseUpdate` usage method:

```
object WithCache{
  val cacheFun1 = collection.mutable.Map[Int, Int]()
  def fun1(i:Int) = i*i
  def catchedFun1(i:Int) = cacheFun1.getOrElseUpdate(i, fun1(i))
}
```

So you can use `catchedFun1` which will check if `cacheFun1` contains key and return value associated with it. Otherwise, it will invoke `fun1`, then cache `fun1`'s result in `cacheFun1`, then return `fun1`'s result.

I can see one potential danger - `cacheFun1` can became to large.  So `cacheFun1` must be cleaned somehow by garbage collector?

P.S. What about `scala.collection.mutable.WeakHashMap and java.lang.ref.*`  ?

Comment: Probably not: http://www.codeinstructions.com/2008/09/weakhashmap-is-not-cache-understanding.html

Answer (score 15):

See the [Memo pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640823/in-scala-2-8-what-type-to-use-to-store-an-in-memory-mutable-data-tablen) and the [Scalaz implementation](http://scalaz.googlecode.com/svn/continuous/latest/browse.sxr/scalaz/Memo.scala.html) of said paper.

Also check out a STM implementation such as [Akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/stm.html).

Not that this is only local caching so you might want to lookinto a distributed cache or [STM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory) such as [CCSTM](http://github.com/nbronson/ccstm), [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/) or [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/)

Comment: Only that the *Memo Pattern* uses `WeahHashMap` and is therefore not a very good cache.

Comment: @Debilski Depends upon "cache" requirements. In this case a "weak cache" works to elevate the posters concerns that "cacheFun1 can [become too] large" ..

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at spray caching (super simple to use)

http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-caching/

makes the job easy and has some nice features

for example :

```
      import spray.caching.{LruCache, Cache}

      //this is using Play for a controller example getting something from a user and caching it
      object CacheExampleWithPlay extends Controller{

        //this will actually create a ExpiringLruCache and hold data for 48 hours
        val myCache: Cache[String] = LruCache(timeToLive = new FiniteDuration(48, HOURS))

        def putSomeThingInTheCache(@PathParam("getSomeThing") someThing: String) = Action {
          //put received data from the user in the cache
          myCache(someThing, () => future(someThing))
          Ok(someThing)
        }

        def checkIfSomeThingInTheCache(@PathParam("checkSomeThing") someThing: String) = Action {
          if (myCache.get(someThing).isDefined)
            Ok(s"just $someThing found this in the cache")
          else
            NotFound(s"$someThing NOT found this in the cache")
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 6):

On the scala mailing list they [sometimes](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/5523) point to the [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) in the [Google collections library](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/). You might want to have a look at that.

Comment: Google Collections has been renamed to Guava, and the new CacheBuilder is probably a closer match: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html

Answer (score 4):

For simple caching needs, I'm still using [Guava cache solution](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) in Scala as well.
Lightweight and battle tested.

If it fit's your requirements and constraints generally outlined below, it could be a great option:

- Willing to spend some memory to improve speed.
- Expecting that keys will sometimes get queried more than once.
- Your cache will not need to store more data than what would fit in RAM. (Guava caches    are local to a single run of your application.
  They do not store data    in files, or on outside servers.)

Example for using it will be something like this:

```
  lazy val cachedData = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
    .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .maximumSize(10)
    .build(
      new CacheLoader[Key, Data] {
        def load(key: Key): Data = {
          veryExpansiveDataCreation(key)
        }
      }
    )
```

To read from it, you can use something like:

```
  def cachedData(ketToData: Key): Data = {
    try {
      return cachedData.get(ketToData)
    } catch {
      case ee: Exception => throw new YourSpecialException(ee.getMessage);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it hasn't been mentioned before let me put on the table the light [Spray-Caching](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-M8/spray-caching/) that can be used independently from Spray and provides expected size, time-to-live, time-to-idle eviction strategies.

Answer (score 2):

We are using Scaffeine (Scala + Caffeine), and you can read abouts its pros/cons compared to other frameworks over [here](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/latency-improvement-with-in-memory-caching-using-caffeine-34713ec77446).

You add your sbt,

```
"com.github.blemale" %% "scaffeine" % "4.0.1"
```

Build your cache

```
import com.github.blemale.scaffeine.{Cache, Scaffeine}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val cachedItems: Cache[String, Int] = 
  Scaffeine()
    .recordStats()
    .expireAtferWrite(60.seconds)
    .maximumSize(500)
    .build[String, Int]()

cachedItems.put("key", 1) // Add items

cache.getIfPresent("key") // Returns an option
```

Comment: Typo from `.build` to `.buid`