# Lightweight caching solution in Scala?

Tags: scala, guava

I just wonder if there is any caching solution available in Scala.
I'm looking for something like it is provided by Guava in Java.

Should I use Guava too in Scala?
Is there a wrapper / pimp in Scalaz or something similar?
Any alternative more appropriate for Scala devs?

What Guava provides:

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> CACHE= CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
       .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });

Supplier<Animal> singleAnimalCache = Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(animalFromDbSupplier(), 365, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

I need some basic cache management like in Guava.

Comment: You unhappy with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651313/how-to-cache-results-in-scala ?

Comment: @om-nom-nom this looks great, I'm looking for a memoizer (like in Guava with Supplyer), but I need some cache management like expiration, max cache size etc. I don't see that in Scalaz implementation

Comment: You wouldn't be the first to use Guava's `Cache` in Scala.

Comment: Twitter has a [helper](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-collection/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/MapMaker.scala) for MapMaker (now adapted to CacheBuilder). Instead I use CacheBuilder directly and have implicits for converting between Guava and Scala types.

Comment: Does this help? [Guava caching in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196290/scala-2-10-type-mismatch-using-google-guavas-cachebuilder/16204579?noredirect=1#16204579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a wrapper / pimp in Scalaz or something similar?

In Scalaz 7 there's `Memo`, which I covered a bit in [learning Scalaz day 16](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day16).

It's the first thing Adam Rosien covered in [scalaz "For the Rest of Us"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcfIH3GYXMI) talk, so check that out too. He's using Scalaz 6.

Comment: Thanks, your link seems great. But the memo provided by Scalaz doesn't seem to support expiration like Guava does

Answer (score 5):

We had the same requirements and ended up building wrappers around Guava. We recently open-sourced parts of the library called [Mango](https://github.com/feijoas/mango). If you don’t mind the extra dependency you can use it like

```
import org.feijoas.mango.common.cache._
import org.feijoas.mango.common.base.Suppliers._

val MY_LISTENER = (remNot: RemovalNotification[Key, Graph]) => ()
// > MY_LISTENER : RemovalNotification[Key,Graph] => Unit = <function1>

val CACHE = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
  .maximumSize(1000)
  .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
  .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
  .build { (key: Key) => new Graph() }
// > CACHE : LoadingCache[Key,Graph] = <function1>

val animalFromDbSupplier = () => {
  // load from db
  new Animal()
}
// > animalFromDbSupplier  : () => Animal = <function0>

val singleAnimalCache = memoizeWithExpiration(animalFromDbSupplier, 365, TimeUnit.DAYS)
// > singleAnimalCache  : () => Animal = Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(<function0>, 365, DAYS)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just adding an answer to plug my own project, but I recommend ScalaCache.

- Supports Guava, Ehcache, Memcached and Redis (or you can plugin your own implementation if you like)
- Simple, idiomatic Scala API
- Support for per-element Time To Live (even for Guava, which doesn't provide that out of the box)
- Support for auto-generation of cache keys using macro magic

https://github.com/cb372/scalacache

Answer (score 3):

Using **guava caching** is straightforward in Scala.

```
import com.google.common.base._
import com.google.common.cache._

object Simple_Guava_Caches_in_Scala {

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

      // Simple scala guava cache
      val simpleCache1 =
         CacheBuilder
           .newBuilder()
           .build(new CacheLoader[String, String] {
              def load(key: String): String = {
                 println(s"Simple scala guava cache, heavy work calculating $key")
                 s"It's me $key"
              }
           })
      println(simpleCache1.get("1"))
      println(simpleCache1.get("1"))
      println(simpleCache1.get("2"))
      println(simpleCache1.get("2"))
      println(simpleCache1.get("2"))


      // Simple scala guava supplier cache / factory
      println()
      val supplier_cache: Supplier[String] = Suppliers.memoize(
         () => {
            println("Simple scala guava supplier cache / factory, heavy work creating singleton:")
            "It's me"
         }
      )
      println(supplier_cache.get)
      println(supplier_cache.get)
      println(supplier_cache.get)
   }
}
```

This is producing

```
Simple scala guava cache, heavy work calculating 1
It's me 1
It's me 1
Simple scala guava cache, heavy work calculating 2
It's me 2
It's me 2
It's me 2

Simple scala guava supplier cache / factory, heavy work creating singleton:
It's me
It's me
It's me
```

I've added this to `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.github.cb372" %% "scalacache-guava" % "0.26.0"
```

Would be interesting to transform the coding above to cb372's scalacache-guava. Could be even simpler/more standardized.