# Scala recursive closure compile error

Tags: scala, recursion, closures

I am trying to implement a memoized Fibonacci number function, and I am running into a compile error that I can't sort out.  The following code is what I have so far.

```
var fibs = Map.empty[Int, Int]
fibs += 0 -> 1
fibs += 1 -> 1
fibs += 2 -> 2
val fib = (n: Int) => {
  if (fibs.contains(n)) return fibs.apply(n)
  else{
    // Error here
    val result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    fibs+= n -> result
    return result
  }
}
println(fib(100))
```

The error is:

> Recursive `fib` needs type

I have tried entering a return type for the closure in various places, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Declaring the closure like `val fib = (n: Int): Int => {` yields a different compile error.

Could you please help me fix this compile error?

Answer (score 5):

You can define a method as suggested by Ben Jackson (i.e. `def fib (n: Int): Int = ...`).

<strike>Function values cannot be recursive.</strike> EDIT: It turns out [they can be recursive](http://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2010/10/31/functional-scala-functions/); you just need to help the type inferencer a bit more. Also, you need to get rid of `return`; it can only be used in the methods.

The following works:

```
var fibs = Map.empty[Int, Int]
fibs += 0 -> 1
fibs += 1 -> 1
fibs += 2 -> 2
val fib: (Int => Int) = n => {
  if(fibs contains n) 
    fibs(n)
  else {
    val result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    fibs += n -> result
    result
  }
}
println(fib(100))
```

---

Also you should take a look at [this blogpost](http://michid.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/function_mem/) to understand how you can abstract away the memoization logic with help of lambdas.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640823/in-scala-2-8-what-type-to-use-to-store-an-in-memory-mutable-data-table

Answer (score 3):

You have to explicitly set the return type of recursive functions.  It can't infer the type because the inference would be cyclic.  So:  `def fib (n: Int): Int = ...`

Comment: Declaring the closure like `val fib = (n: Int): Int => {` yields a different compile error.

Comment: I gave you the `def` syntax.  If you want to use `val` to define the function, you have to give it a type like you normally would:  `val fib: (Int => Int) = (n: Int) => { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `return`, as they can only be used with `def`, not `val`, and declare `fib`'s type, as that's a Scala requirement for recursive definitions.

```
val fib: (Int => Int) = (n: Int) => {
  if (fibs.contains(n)) fibs.apply(n)
  else{
    val result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    fibs+= n -> result
    result
  }
}
```

Note that `fib(100)` will overflow an `Int`