# How to return a function in scala

Tags: function, scala, return-value, go

How can I return a <strike>function</strike> *[side-effecting lexical closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288329/side-effecting-lexical-closure-vs-function-in-scala)*<sup>1</sup>  in Scala?

For instance, I was looking at [this code sample in Go](http://golang.org/doc/play/#598466966704134886):

```
...    
// fib returns a function that returns
// successive Fibonacci numbers.
func fib() func() int {
    a, b := 0, 1
    return func() int {
        a, b = b, a+b
        return b
    }
}
...
println(f(), f(), f(), f(), f())
```

prints 
    1 2 3 5 8

And I can't figure out how to write the same in Scala.

<sup>1. Corrected after [Apocalisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262241/how-to-return-a-function-in-scala/4262932#4262932) comment</sup>

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Slightly shorter, you don't need the return.

```
def fib() = {
    var a = 0
    var b = 1
    () => { 
        val t = a;
        a = b
        b = t + b
        b
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this (just helped me). I want to add that if one desires to explicitly state the return type, one can add ": ReturnType" after the closing "}" (e.g. "} : Int" ).

Answer (score 20):

Gah! Mutable variables?!

```
val fib: Stream[Int] =
  1 #:: 1 #:: (fib zip fib.tail map Function.tupled(_+_))
```

You can return a literal function that gets the nth fib, for example:

```
val fibAt: Int => Int = fib drop _ head
```

EDIT: Since you asked for the functional way of "getting a different value each time you call f", here's how you would do that. This uses Scalaz's `State` monad:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def uncons[A](s: Stream[A]) = (s.tail, s.head)
val f = state(uncons[Int])
```

The value `f` is a state transition function. Given a stream, it will return its head, and "mutate" the stream on the side by taking its tail. Note that `f` is totally oblivious to `fib`. Here's a REPL session illustrating how this works:

```
scala> (for { _ <- f; _ <- f; _ <- f; _ <- f; x <- f } yield x)
res29: scalaz.State[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int],Int] = scalaz.States$$anon$1@d53513

scala> (for { _ <- f; _ <- f; _ <- f; x <- f } yield x)
res30: scalaz.State[scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int],Int]  = scalaz.States$$anon$1@1ad0ff8

scala> res29 ! fib
res31: Int = 5

scala> res30 ! fib
res32: Int = 3
```

Clearly, the value you get out depends on the number of times you call `f`. But this is all purely functional and therefore modular and composable. For example, we can pass any nonempty Stream, not just `fib`.

So you see, you can have effects without side-effects.

Comment: +1 for the answer. The example is great, but, not really what I was looking for/asked. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, you did ask for a function. A side-effenting lexical closure is emphatically not a function.

Comment: I get an `error: type mismatch; found: Int; required: (Int, Int)` on Scala 2.8.1. What's wrong here?

Comment: @Apocalisp I'd just enclose the whole expression inside parenthesis instead using dot notation. `(fib zip fib.tail map Function.tupled(_+_))`. More importantly, using `def` instead of `val` means this definition is not O(1).

Comment: @OscarRyz: What do you mean by "different values after"? In what sense can a function return different values at different times, and what does "after" mean in that context?

Comment: @Apocalisp: Oops! I can barely understand what I wrote,  ehem. Here it goes again:  Is there a *functional* way to have a *side-effecting lexical closure*  returning different values after each invocation in Scala? For instance: `val f = fib(); f(); /*=1*/ f();/*=2*/f();/*=3*/...` Or is it something just not supported by the functional paradigm?

Comment: @OscarRyz: Functional and side-effecting contradict each other. You have to make your state explicit. See the updated answer.

Comment: @Apocalisp: Is there a way of doing `for { _ <- "n times f"; x <- f}` or similar in order to get the nth value?

Comment: @Debiliski: `def times[S,A](n: Int, s: State[S, A]): State[S, A] = if (n < 1) s else for { _ <- s; x <- times(n - 1, s) } yield x`

Comment: Can someone explain the difference between a side-effecting lexical closure and a function here? Google search on "side effecting lexical closure" is returning this question as the only seemingly relevant answer...

Comment: For those wondering, I've got the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22288476/924313). A "side effecting lexical closure" is just a closure (function with an execution environment) with side effects, and "lexical closure" seems to be a fancy term for closures...

Comment: this is more accurate answer for Scala way of doing things, this answer the one should be accepted

Answer (score 8):

While we're sharing cool implementations of the fibonacci function that are only tangentially related to the question, here's a memoized version:

```
val fib: Int => BigInt = {                         
   def fibRec(f: Int => BigInt)(n: Int): BigInt = {
      if (n == 0) 1 
      else if (n == 1) 1 
      else (f(n-1) + f(n-2))                           
   }                                                     
   Memoize.Y(fibRec)
}
```

It uses the memoizing fixed-point combinator implemented as an answer to this question: [In Scala 2.8, what type to use to store an in-memory mutable data table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640823/in-scala-2-8-what-type-to-use-to-store-an-in-memory-mutable-data-table)

Incidentally, the implementation of the combinator suggests a slightly more explicit technique for implementing your <strike>function</strike> side-effecting lexical closure:

```
def fib(): () => Int = {
   var a = 0
   var b = 1
   def f(): Int = {
      val t = a;
      a = b
      b = t + b
      b
  }
  f
}
```

Comment: You can use tupled initalization: `var (a, b) = (0, 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Got it!! after some trial and error:

```
def fib() : () => Int = {
    var a = 0
    var b = 1
    return (()=>{ 
        val t = a;
        a = b
        b = t + b
        b
    })
}
```

Testing:

```
val f = fib()
println(f(),f(),f(),f())

1 2 3 5 8
```

Comment: You can use tupled initalization: `var (a, b) = (0, 1)`. No tupled assignment, however.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a temp var when using a tuple:

```
def fib() = {
  var t = (1,-1)
  () => { 
    t = (t._1 + t._2, t._1)
    t._1
  }
}
```

But in real life you should use Apocalisp's solution.

Comment: +1 heheh well, in real life I wouldn't code fibonacci :) I agree Apocalisp solution is enlightening